# add custom query param to passport auth0 strategy authenticate request

Tags: node.js, passport.js, auth0

I'm using passport.js and auth0 strategy to auth users

I'm also using auth0's hosted login page, which supports query parameters like `customQueryParam` here

ex: `https://cool-startup.auth0.com/login?client=some_client_ID&...bunch of params...&customQueryParam=true`

You can use `customQueryParam` to control the auth0 hosted login page and show flash messages and stuff, its handy

here's my issue

after my auth0 middleware runs and I've determined I need to redirect the user back to my auth0 login page with a custom parameter, how should I accomplish that in the context of using passport.js / is it possible?

I'm looking at the source code here
https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0/blob/master/lib/index.js
which inherits from https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/9ddff909a992c3428781b7b2957ce1a97a924367/lib/strategy.js

and I'm a bit stumped

here is where I find out that I have an error and I need to redirect the user back to auth0 with a custom parameter in the url

```
app.get('/auth/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', 
  {},
  (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      // run passport.authenticate('auth0', 
      // again, but add custom query param 
    }
    return res.redirect('/');
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

any help is greatly appreciated / thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the `/authorize` URL yourself as done here and redirect manually: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-regular-webapp-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/utils/authorize.js

Since the URL is in your control here, you can add any query parameters as you'd like (although sending non-standard query parameters to the login page is something that's generally discouraged).

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I ended up doing, and I can see why its discouraged, but it'll get us over the hump until we move to a pure token approach.